# Laravel 5: Validation error if specific parameter present

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Is there away using Laravel validators, if specific parameter passed return an error, ex: "password" will return an error no matter the value in that parameter:

`[PUT] http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/users/1?password=test // return validation error`

Answer (score 1):

The best way for this would be the creation of a custom validation rule. [Here's](https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-create-custom-validation-rules-laravel/) a good tutorial for this.

In your new validation rule you implement that it only passes if the entered parameters are `null`. You could use a simply null check for this.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the validation logic in order to return an error as soon as the parameter is included in the request, even if the value is `null`, what you can do is concatenate 2 validation rules for this parameter :

1. `nullable` so that your request is valid when the parameter is not present
2. A custom validation rule that is always false so that the request is invalid when the parameter is present

It works like this :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'password' => [
        'nullable',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $fail($attribute.' should not be included.');
        },
    ],
]);
```